# Trying to write a simple function in f# that asks user for input in command line

Tags: f#

Here is my code:

```
open System

let collect_name =
    Console.Write("Enter Your name: ")
    let input = Console.ReadLine()
    printfn input + "Hello"
collect_name
```

I am getting an error when I do this. How do I make the input a string and concatenate the string in f#. I am a total noob thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There's another little problem with your code. You define the `let` as a value (without an argument). That means, it gets initialized before you even call it, and it gets initialized once. It seems more like you're trying to write a _function_ that can be called to get input. Make it `let collect_name() = ...` and call it at some point as `collect_name()`. This will make sure it is evaluated each time you call it, instead of only once.

Answer (score 2):

The printfn function expects a format of what you want to print. e.g.
to print 3. Because is an *int* you do:

```
printfn "%i" 3
```

In your case, you want to print a string:

```
printfn "%s" (input + "Hello")
```

You could also do:

```
printfn "%s Hello" input
```

with the same result.

You can read about all the possible format options here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-%5bfsharp%5d
- https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/

Comment: Small tweak: you could remove the extra string concatenation with this:

`printfn "Hello, %s." input`